# Born approximation for 1D scattering using Green's function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, greens-functions

For $1D$ scattering, we can write a recursive equation for the wave function:
$$\psi(x) = Ae^{ikx}  + \int dx'\frac{e^{ik|(x-x')|}}{2ik}\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}V(x')\psi(x')$$

I am trying to show that asymptotically as $x \rightarrow \infty$:
$$\psi \rightarrow Ae^{ikx} + Ae^{-ikx}\int dx'\frac{e^{2ikx'}}{2ik}\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}V(x')$$ assuming $V$ has compact support

My question is why we can ignore the last term in the following:

As $x\rightarrow -\infty$, $e^{ik|x - x'|} = e^{ik(x' - x)}$, thus by substitution
$$\psi \rightarrow Ae^{ikx} + Ae^{-ikx}\int dx'e^{2ikx'}\frac{m}{ik\hbar^2}V(x') + \int dx'e^{-ik(x-x')}\frac{m}{ik\hbar^2}V(x')\int dx''G(x'',x')V(x'')\psi(x'')$$

where $G(x, y) = \frac{e^{ik|x - y|}}{2ik}.$

I can't see a clear reason why would the double integral be omitted for $x\rightarrow -\infty$ limit. There is only 2 information I can think of : that by definition Born approximation ignores the double integral, or somehow compact support condition helps with the integral.

$\textbf{Note:}$ I think this website is not very friendly with homework-like questions, but I think as long as it is not just 'find this for me' sort of question, we can ask and share what have we done so far and where we find some issue to solve. Lol, some comments in this website has given me anxiety.

Answer (score 0):

I got it next day. The idea is in the Born approximation, you replace $\psi(x')$ by initial planar wave assuming energy is much higher that potential. Directly putting gives the result.